# php.ini not loaded.On winserver2016 deloying php7.4.8+apache2.4.3

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

After install php7, excute phpinfo() within ie, shows

```
loaded configuration File | (none)
```

below the line

```
Configuration File(php.ini) Path | C:\Windows
```

php.ini file has been earlier put in "C:\php-7.4".

httpd.cfg edited PHPIniDir "C:/php-7.4"

Tried:

Cut php.ini into path "C:\Windows", edit httpd.cfg "PHPIniDir"C:\Windows"

Why isn't php.ini loaded?

Comment: remove the `php.ini` from `C:\Windows` that will just cause you issues later. Copy the `php.ini` file into the `Apache\bin` folder

Comment: Of course you have to remember when changing versions of PHP to do this copy again, remembering to make any changes to the new version you made to the current

Comment: Thanks for  your help. Tried copy php.ini into Apache\bin folder and restart apache service, problem still remains.

Comment: These are the related lines in httpd.cfg file:                                                   
...PHPIniDir "C:/php-7.4"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php-7.4/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
AddHandler php7-script php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php7
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

Comment: solved by install php7.3.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install php7.3.18 instead of php7.4.8 and then everything is fine